# Javascript file can't to see events in $_session in php file

Tags: javascript, php

I am a newcomer in php and I have question, this is a piece code which realize edit, reply and delete comment when user logged. My question, what I need to add in events onclick="showForm(<'.$result['id'].'>)", that my file js to start to see, becasue out of $_session js works and see events but when in $_session I have this: Expression statement is not assignment or call

Php file:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['all-good'])) {

        
        echo '<p id="comment-text">'.$result['name'].' '.$result['date'].'<br></p>',
        '<div id="comment-user">',
            '<p id="stealth-<'.$result['id'].'">'.$result['comment'].'</p>',
        '</div>',
        '<form method="post" action="./check%20info/editsavechanges.php">',
            '<textarea id="edit-save-<'.$result['comment'] .'>" name="id-each" hidden><'.$result['id'].'></textarea>',
            '<textarea name="edit-comment"  id="editosa-<'.$result['id'] .'>" class="edit-style" hidden ><'.$result['comment'].'></textarea>',
            '<button type="submit"  name="save-edit-comment"  id="save-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Save</button>',
            '<button type="button" onclick="cancelEdit(<'.$result['id'].'>)" id="cancel-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Cancel</button>',
            '<div id="buttons-forms">',
                '<button type="button" onclick="showForm(<'.$result['id'].'>)" id="open-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" >Edit</button>',
                '<button type="submit"  name="delete-edit-comment" id="delete-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" >Delete</button>',
                '<button type="button"  onclick="showReply(<'.$result['id'].'>)" id="reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" >Reply</button>',
            '</div>',

        '<textarea name="edit-comment-reply"  id="reply-text-<'.$result['id'].'>" class="edit-style-reply" hidden ></textarea>',
        '<button type="submit" name="save-reply-comment"  id="save-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Save</button>',

        '<button type="button" onclick="cancelReply(<'.$result['id'].'>)" id="cancel-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Cancel</button>',
        '<button type="submit"  id="delete-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Delete</button>',
        '<button type="submit"  id="response-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Reply</button>',
        '</form>';


       }else{
        echo '<p id="comment-text">'.$result['name'].' '.$result['date'].'<br></p>',
        '<div id="comment-user">',
            '<p id="stealth-<'.$result['id'] .'>">'.$result['comment'].'</p>',
        '</div>';
    }

    ?>
```

Javascript file:

```
function showForm(id) {
document.getElementById('open-editos-' + id).hidden = true;
document.getElementById('delete-editos-' + id).hidden = true;
document.getElementById('reply-editos-' + id).hidden = true;
document.getElementById('stealth-' + id).hidden = true;
document.getElementById('editosa-' + id).hidden = false;
document.getElementById('save-editos-' + id).hidden = false;
document.getElementById('cancel-editos-' + id).hidden = false;
```

}

Comment: Welcome! Do not post code as images. Include them as formatted text (select the code and click the appropriate format button).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will redo

Answer (score 0):

here is something way way better.

```
//make this file
<?php
class RESPONCEOBJECT{
    public $message = "";
    public $error = false;
    public $data = [];
    public function send(){
        print(json_encode($this));
    }
}
$responseObject = new RESPONCEOBJECT();
?>
```

name it responseObject.php

import as:

```
include_once("responceObject.php"); //point at where the above file is saved
```

```
//for each 'property' you want
array_push($responseObject->data,$result['property']);
//at the end when you have all the data you need.
$responseObject->send();
```

then you handle the display logic and html in javascript.

```
result = fetch("yourURL", anyOptions).then(response=>response.json());
```

Effectively translates the data from php to json, then from json to an javascript object.

the reason this is better is because it separates concerns of data flow and UI logic...
when php starts pushing html... things get weird quickly... the best way to prevent weirdness and quirks is just by separating concerns.

Comment: It's interesting, thank you, I will use and will see

Comment: it's been a really useful pattern for me at least, structuring my php to handle only data has made parsing php much easier as a result.

Comment: Hello again, I used your variant but still have same problems. But yesterday I solved the problem, it turns out when I checked console what she show, I saw ( uncaught syntaxerror unexpected '<' ) and I deleted all < > where were they, now looks like ( '<button type="button"  onclick="showForm('.$result['id'].')" id="open-editos-'.$result['id'].'" >Edit</button>', ) and now buttons  work